# JSON response string ends with "null"

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest, wordpress-plugin-creation

In both Postman and jQuery, I'm getting responses in the form

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}null
```

That trailing null is messing with anything that tries to parse it client-side and I can't figure out where it's coming from. If I `error_log` the encoded JSON before `echo`ing it, there's no trailing null, so I assume that it's a string terminator, but I didn't think that PHP used null-terminated strings. How do I get rid of these nulls?

The object being encoded and returned:

```
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return [
        'internal_id' => $this->internal_id, //int
        'friendly_name' => $this->friendly_name, //string
        'external_id' => $this->external_id, //string
        'picture' => $this->picture //string
    ];
}
```

The actual return statement is just `echo(json_encode($retval));`

Comment: It's not a string terminator, but *something* in your PHP script must be producing it. Have you got a second `json_encode` call left over from writing the code? PHP's debug functions (var_dump/export) display null in upper-case, so it's unlikely to be one of those.

Comment: can we see the code that outputs the JSON?

Comment: I added the jsonSerialize method. The null doesn't show up in var_dump *at all.* The closing brace is the last character of the string.

Comment: Any code executing after the echo(json_encode()) must be producing the output of 'null'. Probably a var_dump(), print_r() or something?

Comment: It ended up being the implicit `return null` if you don't exit the function manually. All fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a PHP file has executed, you have to exit manually or return instead of echoing, otherwise it'll return `NULL` implicitly and mess everything up. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant probably... but this SAVED me:

```
function removeTrailingNulls(__str){
    var sanitized = __str;
    var lastCharIndex = sanitized.length - 1;
    var lastChar = sanitized[lastCharIndex];
    var lastCharCode = lastChar.charCodeAt(0);
    var isWeirdNullSpace = lastCharCode === 0; 
    console.log('checking last char (' + lastChar + ') code: ' + lastCharCode + '...null space end?' + isWeirdNullSpace);
    var loopCount = 0;
    while(isWeirdNullSpace){
        sanitized = sanitized.substring(0, sanitized.length-1);
        lastChar = sanitized[sanitized.length-1];
        lastCharCode = lastChar.charCodeAt(0);
        isWeirdNullSpace = lastCharCode === 0;              
        loopCount++;
        if(loopCount>100) break; // prevent infinite loops just in case.
    }
    return String(sanitized);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code in addition to the correct answer stated above from Kenny. This prevents 0 or NULL output at the end of the json:

> "Once a PHP file has executed, you have to exit manually or return
> instead of echoing, otherwise it'll return NULL implicitly and mess
> everything up. Lesson learned."

```
ob_clean(); // Clears the output buffer to remove unexpected characters
echo json_encode($array);
exit(); // Terminates the script to prevent further output
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this error from an AJAX call to a PHP script when you use `echo` to send data back to the front end.

To terminate the PHP script where you `echo`, you have to kill the script by using `die` and `exit` and some cases `return` like so

```
$arrayToJsonData = ["some", "array", "result"];  
echo(json_encode($arrayToJsonData));
//Kill the script here by using die or exit
die;
```